# After pickle.damp a list into a txt, some strange characters appear

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pickle
new = open("all.txt", "wb")
files = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
def toTxt(dir):
    global new
    pickle.dump(files, new)
    new.close()        

dir = "C:\\python36\\captions"
toTxt(dir)
```

**after calling it, the all.txt is:**

€]q (X   aaaqX   bbbqX   cccqe.

**where these strange characters, like €]q (X, come from? how to eliminate them?**

Answer (score 1):

`pickle.dump` is for python object, and it includes some meta infos. If you write the strings to all.txt, following code does it, just for an example.

```
import os
files = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

def toTxt(dir):
    fname = os.path.sep.join([dir, "all.txt"])
    with open(fname, "wb") as f:
        for file in files:
            f.write(file.encode('utf-8'))

dir = "." # current directory
toTxt(dir)
```